# Differentiating "on" click events in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page which has an event as follows:

```
$(document).on("click","#div",function(e){

//do the operation

});
```

This event gets executed on both page load as well as div click.
I need to differentiate between these two calls inside the event, because I have to write a condition extra only on div click and not on load .

How do I know if its from page load or div click?

Edit

On load:

$(default).find('a').trigger("click") ; makes it trigger on load

Comment: Why would that be triggered on page load?

Comment: it shouldn't trigger on page load, put an alert inside that and verify.

Comment: I was also wondering of the same, its a maintanance application which is created already, and after research, it says that "when $(document).on() is used , it gets attached to the parent element"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("click", "#div", function(e) {

  if (e.originalEvent !== undefined) {//use the originalEvent
    alert('human');
  } else {
    alert('load click')
  }

});


$('#div').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>click</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
//You can check for originalEvent element present in event object.
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click","#div",function(e){

    if(e.originalEvent) {
      alert('clicked manually');
    } else {
      alert('page load');
    }

  });

  $('#div').click();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="div">
    div
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a boolean variable in each of these like:

```
var fromPageLoad = false;
var fromDivClick = false;

$(window).load(function() {
    fromPageLoad = true;
    //do the operation
});

$(document).on("click","#div",function(e){
    fromDivClick = true;
    //do the operation
});
```

and then check which condition is true with an if or a switch statement.

**[EDIT]**
Unless you want alerts popping out of the blue like the other answers suggest settings variables as so is the way to go.

Comment: Where exactly would you put the check? That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me...

Comment: I didn't ask this question so I can't really share any code :P I see you edited your answer, now it makes a bit more sense at least...

Answer (score 0):

if u need to perform any action on page load you have to specify as below

```
$(document).load(function(){
  alert("event on page load");
});
```

if the div click event then as below

`$(#div).onclick(function(){
alert ("on div click");
})`